# Python Celery - Permission Issue - Unable to upload files from a download task

Tags: python, django, celery

I have a Celery task whose job is to download files to a local directory, and then upload to a S3 bucket when download is complete.

My issue is that with a recent update of the workers, I'm getting permission denied errors when accessing the folder to upload.  The code was fundamentally unchanged other than from going to script-method to class based implementation.

I made a task just to create the directories, with a single method call:

```
os.mkdirs(path, 777)
```

and it creates the directory with permissions `300`

This is despite

```
CELERYD_USERS='ubuntu'
CELERYD_GROUP='ubuntu'
CELERYD_CREATE_DIRS=1
```

in the config.

According to the [docs](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/tutorials/daemonizing.html#example-django-configuration), the last option allows celery to create a directory owned byt the user/group specified above.  That much is happening, but nothing is said about *permissions*.

Is there any way around this?

Comment: Hi, were you able to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The CELERY_CREATE_DIR only tells celery create its operational directories:

> Always create directories (log directory and pid file directory). Default is to only create directories when no custom logfile/pidfile set.

I believe your problem is with the `os.mkdirs`. According to the [os.mkdir doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.mkdir), `mode` may be ignored on your system and you need to use `os.chmod` to change the mode.